# How long does it take for a GCP backend service to stop sending connections to an instance after being removed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I am using a GCP region [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service) to load balance across a set of instances in an unmanaged instance group. When I [remove](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances#removing_vms) an instance from the group I want to know when I can safely delete the instance.

Connection draining is set to 0 seconds so as hinted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71098566/6180803) post I am waiting until the instance no longer shows up in the [health statuses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/backendServices/getHealth) of the backend service group and then waiting for an extra 60 seconds before deleting the instance; I assume the 60 seconds is required for the health status decision to be applied across GCP, but the only place I can find this time period mentioned is [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions#connection_draining_causing_delays) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/enabling-connection-draining), neither of which are definitive.

Is there any way to tell through the GCP APIs when I can safely remove an instance or do I need to make this decision using instance metrics (e.g. by waiting until no new connections have been made for a period of time).

Answer (score -1):

You can use API call [`backendServices.list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/backendServices/list) to verify if the instance is still member of the backend service.

Comment: This only shows the backend groups but doesn't give information about the instances in the groups, that is why I am using the health statuses

Comment: In the same link, you can also read abour [backendServices.getHealth](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/backendServices/getHealth)

Comment: Yeah I link out to that same page in the question, but given GCP is a distributed system I wanted confirmation about whether it's safe to remove the instance as soon as it's no longer in the health status response or whether it's necessary to allow more time for the information to propagate